# TabItem Header alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть TabControl. Табы у него фиксированного размера, а `Header` располагается по центру таба. А мне надо прижать его к левому краю (или растянуть), но я не знаю как это сделать, какие свойства менять.

**UPD:**

Меня не правильно понимают, поэтому попытаюсь обрисовать проблему. К сожалению я не могу видеть картинки в сообщениях, поэтому остается надеяться, что она есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выше - как есть, ниже - как хочу чтобы было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно установить свойство у TabControl:

```
<TabControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <TabItem Width="200" Header="Header">
        <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**UPD**

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне не нужно позиционировать контент, мне нужно позиционировать хеадер

Comment: точнее контент хеадера )

Comment: и желательно не меняя `TabItem.Template`

Comment: Это и есть позиционирование контента заголовка.

Comment: Сбило с толку определение `TabItem` :). Спасибо, `<TabControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">` - то что надо!